# Difference between "estimated" and "fitted"?

Tags: estimation, fitting

Currently I am using a r package to fit an ARMA-GARCH process. Afterwards, I want to use the fitted values to calculate the Value at Risk. So these values are not the forecasts, but the "in-sample-fit". Now, I am wondering about the word-choice, i.e. the difference between the word "fitted" and "estimated"? What word should I use? Is it the same?

E.g. [Tsay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471415448) page 136 says in figure 3.8

> "Time series plot of estimated volatilty ($\sigma_t$) for monthly
>   excess returns ...."

Whereas in the R manual it says:

> "fitted values"

Answer (score 3):

I think the term "fitted" is mostly used in regression frameworks where you fit a line through data. For example: $\hat{y}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x$. The value of the fitted line at the data point $x_{i}$ is then called the fitted value or the predicted value at this point ($\hat{y_{i}}$). The term estimate is in generally used whenever you estimate a population parameter - that might be a slope, mean, standard deviation etc. - from a sample. For example: we say we estimate the population mean $\mu$ by the sample mean $\bar{x}$, so $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}$. Parameter estimates are usually denoted by a hat operator: $\hat{\sigma}$, $\hat{y_{i}}$, $\hat{\mu}$ etc. So the predicted value in a regression ($\hat{y_{i}}$) can also be seen as an estimate at the point $y_{i}$.

Comment: I agree; with the trivial change that the line fitted can be a curve or surface. Parameters are estimated, models are fitted, but often by the same calculation, e.g. command or function call. "Fitted" and "predicted" overlap in usage. Fitted and predicted values are usually for a response (outcome, dependent) variable.  "Predicted" is not confined to something about the future. However, your context is time series, and time series have their own terminology, which sometimes differs subtly from the rest of statistics. I don't think there is much talk of "forecasting" elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Often you want to fit a model, not values. The estimate of parameters of this model are then estimated using an estimator, that is a specific estimation technique. For example in Tsay, the standard deviation (volatility) is a parameter that is estimated. It sounds clear to me. In the R manual, "fitted values" sounds very unclear. Are they speaking about evaluations from an already fitted model?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf page 71-72